# Can I set a mount order via stab

Tags: mount

I have a Mac mini, and am using /etc/fstab to mount iTunes folders, one under each other.  My stab looks like this:

```
# Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)
#
# Failure to do so is unsupported and may be destructive.
UUID=76833548-F7C1-4A74-8D58-A1D5EB48B59F /Users/kdm/Music/iTunes apfs rw,noauto,noowners,nobrowse 0 2
UUID=2B3A9042-5060-47CB-B411-F2AE67D60A06 /Users/kdm/Music/iTunes/iTunes\040Media/TV\040Shows apfs rw,noauto,noowners,nobrowse 0 2
```

The problem is that I need to have the second mount happen after the first, which isn't guaranteed.  I'm aware that I could potentially script this, or something similar, but I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to make sure `iTunes` is mounted before `iTunes/Media/TV Shows` using built in functionality.

Comment: Why do you need to mount the volumes in that order?

Comment: You have `noauto` specified so how are you mounting them?  If they weren't `noauto` then they should be processed top to bottom (by `mount -a` for example) so `iTunes` would exist before you try to mount the `TV Shows` within it.  According to the fstab [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/5/fstab/) *"The order of records in fstab is important because diskarbitrationd(8), fsck(8), mount(8), and umount(8) sequentially iterate through fstab doing their thing."*